# How to Create ManyToMany Through Model without Keys in Django?

Tags: django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have 3 tables:

Table A

Table B

Table C

Table A has a foreign key to Table B.  Table C has a foreign key to Table B.  So B acts as an intermediary through table, but it does not have any foreign keys to A or C itself, so I cannot declare a ManyToManyField from A to C in the conventional way, but I would like to do so in order to use prefetch_related when grabbing C records from A.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This could also be thought of as a ManyToOneToMany relation.